# Google Maps JavaScript Charge but hidden on CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps

im working with Google Maps APIs to JavaScript , but the map doesn't charge

```
div id="exTab2" class="container">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  base_url();?>assets/js/script.js"></script>

  <div  class="container" onload="initMap();">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Bievenido
          </h1>
           <div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">

          var map;
          function initMap() {
            console.log('cargando mapas');
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 8
            });
          }

              </script>
              <script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykeyxxxxxxx&callback=initMap">
              </script>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In console:

> cargando mapas

But in my html inspector:[image]

But the map doesn't appear in browser

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load all of your javascript before your content.

You cannot call onload when the function is created after the page renders...

I assume it should load roughly in this order...

```
<div id="exTab2" class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</script>
<script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykeyxxxxxxx&callback=initMap">
              </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  base_url();?>assets/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
console.log('cargando mapas');
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
    });
}

</script>

  <div  class="container" onload="initMap();">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Bievenido
          </h1>
           <div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the height to 100% on the wrapping div, set it to 100% on the map div itself, e.g.

```
<div style="height: 100%" id="map"></div>
```

Here is a jsbin example (you'll need to add your API key):

http://jsbin.com/hivovukiqu/edit?html,output